# Почему IsBackground не работает?

Tags: c#, winforms

Изучаю C#. Подскажите, почему поток не становится асинхронным после `IsBackground` (окно просто подвисает пока едет кнопка)? Как правильно?

```
public delegate void HelperToColl();
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    HelperToColl HTC;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HTC = new HelperToColl(car_1_race);
    }

    private void Start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread car_1 = new Thread(car_1_race);
        car_1.IsBackground = true;
        Invoke(HTC);
    }
    public  void car_1_race()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Car_1_btn.Left += rnd.Next(1, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Код у тебя странный... Ты пуляешь в отдельный поток метод, но НЕ запускаешь и вместо этого вызываешь делегат HTC.

Должно быть как-то вот так(Я набросал свой пример работы):

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var thread=new Thread(WriteTxt);
        thread.Start();
    }



 private void WriteTxt()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)//Если обращаешься к UI из того же потока
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("1\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Invoke(new Action<string>(richTextBox1.AppendText),"1\n");//Иначе делаем Invoke.
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

И на заметку:

Потоки- это низкоуровневая штуку, сейчас более актуальны Task.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужна многопоточность в вашем коде, поскольку изменение свойств контролов всё равно должно производиться в главном потоке.

Воспользуйтесь лучше современным async/await:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RandomCarMovement();
    }

    private async Task RandomCarMovement()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Car_1_btn.Left += rnd.Next(1, 3);
        }
    }
}
```